# Class ZipArchive not found, but zip extension installed and enabled

Tags: php, phpexcel, php-ziparchive, php-7.1

I am using PHPExcel to read excel files filled with customer data.

```
    $file = $this->suppdata['impfile'];
    $type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($file);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($type);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $highestRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();

    $data = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray(
        'A7:' . $highestColumn . $highestRow,
        NULL,TRUE,FALSE
    );
```

Nothing fancy. Special on this is, that I run this code on a background process started by `exec`. I do this because loading and (further) processing the data can take some time, and I don't want the users to wait for this. It works for CSV and TXT files, and as far as I know it *used* to work on XLS(X) too.

Now, when processing a XLSX file, I get this error:

`Class 'ZipArchive' not found`

The obvious approach would be to check if the zip extension is enabled and if not, enable it. I did this, but `phpinfo()` displays the zip extension as loaded and enabled.

The project runs on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.1.11. On my local machine I use Windows 10 and PHP 7.1.11, everything works just fine.

So the question is, why is the extension disabled for the script above, but enabled in general?

Comment: If you're doing this as  background process using exec, then is the php_zip extension enabled for the CLI?

Comment: First, use queues instead of exec(). Second, how are you executing the code?

Comment: @MarkBaker I checked this and noticed that the process uses PHP 7.0.22. But when I connect via SSH to the server and type in `php -i` it displays information for PHP 7.1.11. How can I set which version the CLI uses?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Do you mean how I start the process? It's called like this `exec('php php_file.php 7 input_file.xlsx on')` (*7* and *on* are parameters the php file needs to work with).

Comment: Changing the version of your PHP depends on your setup. What do you have installed on your server as a web server?

Comment: PHP is running as a FastCGI Application served by Apache. I crawled through the file system and found that the PHP-Cli doesn't has zip.so installed in it's extension dir. Should I try to install the ziplib to this version or rather switch the cli version (if possible)?

Comment: I got it working by calling the absolute path of the php bin in the script (`exec("/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php ...")`. Is that ok to do so?